# Coming back with a 4D Crossword!

Tags: crosswords, four-dimensional

This puzzle is part of the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #43: Variety Crossword Grids](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7062/fortnightly-topic-challenge-43-variety-crossword-grids?cb=1).

The clues are in random order.

**The Blank Grid**
[image]

**Across**

```
Nevertheless
Expected to happen
Sign of distress
Lid or cover
Take a chance
K-pop group
Web of skin
```

**Down**

```
Large, round container
Take in deep breaths
12 to 12
Arrest a criminal
Short literature
Liquid from wound
Consume
Pig mama
```

**Through**

```
Month of the mid-autumn
Warm eggs
Before this moment
Not a man of culture
Public transport
History. Period
Hidden home
Public transport
Net of threads
Oriental new year
A general name for all the states
Like snake like fish
Greater than the King
```

**Along**

```
The method to solve a problem
Transparent crystal
Yellow hole-y character
Had one's weight supported by buttocks
Before
Blue
Companion
Eye
X or W split
The sense of respecting oneself
Nevertheless
Fall behind
Value
```

**Key regarding the names of directions**

[image]

**Hint**

> Out of @JeremyDover's answer, 6 grids have the wrong answer (including blanks)

Comment: Is there an across clue missing?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore no. cant disclose more.

Comment: Is it intentional that two of the words don't actually connect to the rest of the grid?

Comment: @Deusovi yes it is.

Comment: I actually created this exact same grid (without the two disconnected words) yesterday, but didn't yet have the time to fill it in with words :-)

Comment: @Bass i- great minds think alike :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some back-and-forth with the OP, I fixed up the middle through and along answers. One square is still wrong, but I'm danged if I can figure out which one.

The almost-complete grid:

> [image: Almost complete grid]

The Clues:

**ACROSS**

> (NIL)
>  (YET) Nevertheless
>  (DUE) Expected to happen
>  (SOS) Sign of distress
>  (TOP) Lid or cover
>  (BET) Take a chance
>  (BTS) K-pop group
>  (WEB) Web of skin

**DOWN**

> (TUB) Large, round container
>  (SOB) Take in deep breaths
>  (DAY) 12 to 12
>  (NAB) Arrest a criminal
>  (LIT) Short literature
>  (PUS) Liquid from wound
>  (EAT) Consume
>  (SOW) Pig mama

**THROUGH**

> (SEP) Month of the mid-autumn
>  (SIT) Warm eggs
>  (AGO) Before this moment
>  (YOB) Not a man of culture
>  (BUS) Public transport
>  (ERA) History. Period
>  (DEN) Hidden home
>  (CAB) Public transport
>  (WEB) Net of threads
>  (TET) Oriental new year
>  (USA) A general name for all the states
>  (EEL) Like snake like fish
>  (ACE) Greater than the King

**ALONG**

> (WAY) The method to solve a problem
>  (ICE) Transparent crystal
>  (BOB) Yellow hole-y character
>  (SAT) Had one's weight supported by buttocks
>  (ERE) Before
>  (SAD) Blue
>  (PAL) Companion
>  (SEE) Eye
>  (TEN) X or W split
>  (EGO) The sense of respecting oneself
>  (BUT) Nevertheless
>  (LAG) Fall behind
>  (USE) Value

Comment: A lot of your answers match my own (though you've done far better than I did at getting them all together in the grid). I hate to break it to you though - there's some WEB/WEN confusion going on that breaks your current attempt - sorry! +1 for the progress though...

Comment: @Stiv...Grrr, mistake there...fixed now. I originally had wen, since I didn't think it could be web, but things fit a lot better with web. I understand the obvious objection, and share it, but...I figure it's gotta be close, or the setter laid a heck of a trap I stumbled into :-)

Comment: Yes, I had WEB for ages but it just felt wrong... Almost all my answers agree, but if SEP is correct I'd like to ask the OP in which part of the world that constitutes MID-Autumn! (That would suggest Autumn begins in August to me - not a chance!) ;-)

Comment: hint: it isnt web/wen

Comment: u interested in finishing the rest or not?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Haven't had time, unfortunately...if it's still open later in the week, I'll take another look.

Comment: Has the OP confirmed there should be 2 WEBs? Because you have two...

Answer (score 0):

### OP's Full Answer

This has been left idle for too long, plus JeremyDover has almost finished it, so imma accept that answer and post the true answer here:

> [image]

Explanation and respective clues can be found [here :D](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SpLWOCswEFr7_AOVTcBKaKjeuWfgv-lhMiHCs95LuXw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Ah, no wonder Jeremy had problems finishing it off - "Black flying animal" does not appear as a clue in your puzzle! Instead you have "public transport" twice, hence why he has both BUS and CAB among his answers! :)

Comment: oh no..... thanks for spotting that out!